# Send FCM push notification to sip client app on Android based on pn-param and pn-prid URI Parameters

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, sip, rfc

I want to send push notifications from my PBX/SIP-Server (FreePBX 15/Asterisk 17)
to sip client apps that provide 'pn-provider', 'pn-param' and 'pn-prid' URI Parameters as specified in [rfc8599/draft-ietf-sipcore-sip-push-29](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-sipcore-sip-push-29.html#rfc.section.11) during REGISTER sip request, e.g.

```
xyz@1xx.1xx.2xx.198:9926;transport=TLS;pn-provider=fcm;pn-param=com.mizuvoip.mizudroid.app;pn-prid=dcrpn1TbEW0:APA91bGgK3RV-s7AX-U2...HLoQL1UNgom
```

What I haven't managed/do NOT understand so far is how to successfully create a push notification with the device token in 'pn-prid' submitted by the sip client app   (NOTE: This is a 3rd party(!) app, for which I neither possess a SenderID nor a ServerKey from its linked Firebase project. In my case, I use and tried before with MizuDroid sip client APP for Android.)

Attempts to send a PUSH notification via [FCM HTTP REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) using a ServerKey from a Firebase project I have registered before all resulted in

```
{"multicast_id":2435751791125788205,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to send FCM PUSH notifications to 3rd party(!) apps from which you have already obtained a device token (here: in 'pn-prid' URI parameter)
2. If answer 1 is yes: What FCM API do I need to use, what data do I need to submit for the purpose and what are the further prerequisites

Comment: Have you figured out more about this?  I'm having a similar issue with Linphone Android - was wondering whether Firebase allows me to generate PNs for this app even though I do not own the app.